# Kubernetes: using container as proxy

Tags: kubernetes, networking, amazon-eks

I have the following pod setup:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: proxy-test
  namespace: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: container-a
      image: <Image>
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 8083
    - name: container-proxy
      image: <Image>
      ports:
        - name: server
          containerPort: 7487
          protocol: TCP
    - name: container-b
      image: <Image>
```

I `exec` into `container-b` and execute following curl request:

```
curl --proxy localhost:7487 -X POST http://localhost:8083/
```

Due to some reason, `http://localhost:8083/` is directly getting called and proxy is ignored. Can someone explain why this can happen ?

Comment: Almost certainly because in most operating systems, `localhost` and its 127.0.0.1 sibling are in `NO_PROXY` (even if implicitly); if you want to contact `container-a` via the proxy, then use its in-cluster DNS name or the Pod's IP to inform curl you really do want the network request to leave that "machine"

Comment: @mdaniel thanks for the reply. I think it makes sense. One more question if you can answer, is `localhost` traffic also handled through `docker0` ?

Comment: It would be surprising, since localhost and 127.0.0.1 have their own network interface, `lo`, which is for 127/8 traffic

Answer (score 1):

### Environment

I replicated the scenario on `kubeadm` and `GCP GKE` kubernetes clusters to see if there is any difference - no, they behave the same, so I assume AWS EKS should behave the same too.

I created a pod with 3 containers within:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: proxy-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu # client where connection will go from
    name: ubuntu
    command: ['bash', '-c', 'while true ; do sleep 60; done']
  - name: proxy-container # proxy - that's obvious
    image: ubuntu
    command: ['bash', '-c', 'while true ; do sleep 60; done']
  - name: server # regular nginx server which listens to port 80
    image: nginx
```

For this test stand I installed `squid` proxy on `proxy-container` ([what is squid and how to install it](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/proxy-servers-squid)). By default it listens to port `3128`.

As well as `curl` was installed on `ubuntu` - client container. (`net-tools` package as a bonus, it has `netstat`).

### Tests

**Note!**

- I used `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` because `squid` has some resolving questions, didn't find an easy/fast solution.
- `curl` is used with `-v` flag for verbosity.

We have `proxy` on `3128` and `nginx` on `80` within the pod:

```
# netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3128            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

`curl` directly:

```
# curl 127.0.0.1 -vI

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80... # connection goes directly to port 80 which is expected
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
```

`curl` via proxy:

```
# curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:3128 127.0.0.1:80 -vI

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3128... # connecting to proxy!
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3128 (#0) # connected to proxy
> HEAD http://127.0.0.1:80/ HTTP/1.1 # going further to nginx on `80`
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
```

`squid` logs:

```
# cat /var/log/squid/access.log

1635161756.048      1 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 958 GET http://127.0.0.1/ - HIER_DIRECT/127.0.0.1 text/html
1635163617.361      0 127.0.0.1 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 352 HEAD http://127.0.0.1/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

### NO_PROXY

`NO_PROXY` environment variable might be set up, however by default it's empty.

I added it manually:

```
# export NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1

# printenv | grep -i proxy
NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1
```

Now `curl` request via proxy will look like:

```
# curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:3128 127.0.0.1 -vI

* Uses proxy env variable NO_PROXY == '127.0.0.1' # curl detects NO_PROXY envvar
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80... # and ignores the proxy, connection goes directly
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
```

It's possible to override `NO_PROXY` envvar while executing `curl` command with `--noproxy` flag.

> --noproxy no-proxy-list
>
> Comma-separated list of hosts which do not use a proxy, if one is specified. The only wildcard is a single *
> character, which matches all hosts, and effectively disables the
> proxy. Each name in this list is matched as either a domain which
> contains the hostname, or the hostname itself. For example, local.com
> would match local.com, local.com:80, and [www.local.com](http://www.local.com), but not
> [www.notlocal.com](http://www.notlocal.com). (Added in 7.19.4).

Example:

```
# curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:3128 --noproxy "" 127.0.0.1 -vI

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3128... # connecting to proxy as it was supposed to
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3128 (#0) # connection to proxy is established
> HEAD http://127.0.0.1/ HTTP/1.1 # connection to nginx on port 80
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
```

This proves that proxy works! with localhost.

**Another option** is something incorrectly configured in `proxy` which is used in the question. You can get this pod and install `squid` and `curl` into both containers and try yourself.

Comment: i will make a test with squid